# How to correctly output variables in Jade templating engine?

Tags: node.js, variables, pug, template-engine

I was using links like `a(href="#{settings.url}")` but someone told me that i could just do `a(href=settings.url)`, which is a better solution (although I do not understand the difference).

But now i have a question for another use case. Which one should i use, If any? And Why?

1. `link(rel="stylesheet", href="#{settings.url}/assets/css/main.css")`
2. `link(rel="stylesheet", href=settings.url + "/assets/css/main.css")`

Comment: I think it's a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say there is not a very important difference, but let's take a look behind the scenes:

**First example:**

```
link(rel="stylesheet", href="#{locals.url}/assets/css/main.css")
```

with data

```
{ url: 'www.example.com' }
```

produces this code

```
function template(locals) {
    var buf = [];
    var jade_mixins = {};
    buf.push('<link rel="stylesheet"' + jade.attr("href", "" + locals.url + "/assets/css/main.css", true, false) + "/>");
    return buf.join("");
}
```

and this HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="www.example.com/assets/css/main.css"/>
```

**Secondly:**

```
link(rel="stylesheet", href=locals.url + "/assets/css/main.css")
```

will (with the same data as above) produce

```
function template(locals) {
    var buf = [];
    var jade_mixins = {};
    buf.push('<link rel="stylesheet"' + jade.attr("href", locals.url + "/assets/css/main.css", true, false) + "/>");
    return buf.join("");
}
```

and result in HTML (surprise!):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="www.example.com/assets/css/main.css"/>
```

**Lesson learned:**
You see the difference in both "methods" is marginal (see the `"" +` in the frist example). Ergo use whatever pleases you best.

Comment: So the second one is more optimized although it doesn't really matter because the difference is almost none. Thanks for the deep research!