# Send variable from backbone view to jade template

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, pug

I have the following template in my index.jade:

```
....
<script type="text/template" id="sample-template">
  a(href="<%= link.href %>") <%= link.title %>
</script>
....
```

And I have the below code in my backbone view which sends a variable called `link` to index.jade.

```
....
var SampleView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template($('#sample-template').html()),

  render: function() {
    this.$el.append(this.template({
      link: this.model.toJSON()
    }));
    return this;
  }
});
....
```

Now when I render that template I get the following output:

```
<a href="<%= link.href %>"> sample link
```

You see, I got the correct output for `title` variable. But the problem is with `href`. It doesn't print the value of `link.href`.

Comment: Have you tried removing the double-quotes from the href assignment? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22780682/382982) answer.

Comment: @pdoherty926 yes I removed double-quotes and I got following error: `unexpected token <`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out what is wrong with it. Because `jade` is a template engine that works with `node` (actually in server side), it has a lack of support in client side usage. So when you compile a `jade` template with underscore `_.template` function, you can't expect a functional template file.
But there is an alternative way of sending variables from backbone view to jade template. You can create a helper function which print what ever you want in a jade template.

```
....
var SampleView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template($('#sample-template').html()),

  render: function() {
    this.$el.append(this.template({
      link: this.model.toJSON(),
      ahref: this.ahref
  }));
  return this;
  },

  ahref: function( href, title ) {
    return '<a href=' + href + '>' + title + '</a>';
  }

});
....
```

Then I need to pass `link` helper function into the jade template.

```
....
<script type="text/template" id="sample-template">
  ahref(link.href, link.title);
</script>
....
```